# Do fully optimizing compilers for terminating programs exist?

Tags: computability, compilers, program-optimization

In Andrew W. Appel's book, *Modern Compiler Implementation in ML*, he says under chapter 17 that *Computability theory shows that it will always be possible to invent new optimizing transformations* and proceeds to prove that a *fully optimizing compiler* will solve the halting problem: A program *Q* that produces no output and never halts can easily be replaced by its optimal representation, *Opt(Q)*, being "L: goto L". So a fully optimizing compiler can solve the halting problem.

So my question is this: **Does a fully optimizing compiler exist for terminating programs?** My only thoughts are the following: Even though a program is guaranteed to terminate, it can still be arbitrarily complex, and for any concrete optimizing compiler, C, one could perhaps construct a program that takes C as input and somehow produces a worse program as some kind of corner case.

Also, **What are the implications of restricting ourselves to terminating programs?**

Comment: It is hard to even find the optimal instruction sequence for a single block of code with no control flow at all.  The [superoptimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superoptimization) article on Wikipedia gives a good intro (with citations.)

Comment: The Wikipedia article mentions that superoptimization looks at loop-free sequences of instructions. Having no loops, I suppose, is another way of saying that it terminates. From looking briefly at the available references, it appears to be possible but extremely expensive.

Comment: What is the meaning of "optimise" here? Smaller runtime? If so, which: worst-case, average-case, every-case, some-case, ...?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I assume you are interested in optimisation of runtime. As I've written in my comment, that does not sufficiently specify the goal: does an optimisation reduce runtime on *any* input, *every* input, all *worst-case* inputs or even *on average*?

I will show that all of them are impossible. The proof extends to optimising the length of the program.

Recall that the following problem is not computable:

> Given a context-free grammar $G$ with terminal alphabet $\Sigma$, decide whether
>   $\mathcal{L}(G) = \Sigma^*$.

Note furthermore that given a context-free grammar $G$, we can hardcode, say, the CYK algorithm for that one grammar; denote this algorithm by $\mathrm{CYK}_G$. We observe that $\mathrm{CYK}_G$ terminates for all inputs (from $\Sigma^*$).

Now assume that there is an optimiser $\operatorname{Opt}$ which, given an always terminating algorithm $A$, outputs a result-equivalent algorithm which is optimal with respect to runtime. Clearly,

$\qquad \operatorname{Opt}(\mathrm{CYK}_G) = \text{'}\mathtt{return\ true;}\text{'}
        \iff \mathcal{L}(G) = \Sigma^*$

and we have thus constructed a decider for an uncomputable problem, contradicting the assumption.

Comment: Thank you for this argument. A few clarifying questions: What is $\Sigma*$? I assume $\mathcal{L}(G)$ is the language generated by grammar $G$.

Comment: @Simon: $\Sigma^{\ast}$ is the set of all words. Raphael: Nice proof. In fact you do not need context-free grammars; instead, given a Turing machine $M$ you can create a program $\mathrm{P}_M(i)$ that simulates $M$ for $i$ steps and returns true if the machine reaches an accepting state. Then $\operatorname{OPT}(\mathrm{P}_M)$ would be $\text{'}\mathtt{return\ false;}\text{'}$ iff $M$ does not halt.