# Minimizing DPDA

Tags: optimization, pushdown-automata

Is there an **efficient** algorithm for minimizing a deterministic PDA in terms of states? Is it even computable?

I know that it is not possible to minimize a [PDA](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/37461/755) in general, but my question is about *deterministic* PDA.

For tools like lexer generators, where occasionally a counter or a stack would be needed to lex languages with string interpolation or other constructs, the question for DPDAs would be interesting as well. The answer - and the algorithm - is well known for deterministic finite automata and to my knowledge, some lexer generator tools do utilize that.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding.  If you care about minimizing the number of states, it *is* possible to minimize a PDA: you can always translate the PDA into a PDA with a single state.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/37461/755.  Do you really mean, minimize the number of states?

Comment: Depending on the exact definition of "minimize", minimization seems like it might be decidable, given decidability of equivalence testing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_pushdown_automaton#Equivalence_problem  (namely, enumerate all "smaller" DPDAs, by whatever notion of "smaller" you use).  Maybe you mean to ask whether there is an efficient algorithm?

Comment: @D.W. Yes, I'm specifically asking for an efficient algorithm that could be applied to software mentioned in my OP.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to correct the mistakes and to include all relevant information the question, so people don't need to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  Thank you!